# Spring RestTemplate certificate 403 Forbidden: [no body]

Tags: spring-boot, rest, resttemplate, client-certificates

I use p12 certificate with RestTemplate to call an external API.

RestTemplate:

```
final SSLContext sslContext = new SSLContextBuilder()
                    .loadTrustMaterial(keyStoreFile.getURL(), keyPassword.toCharArray(), (X509Certificate[] chain, String authType) -> true)
                    .build();
            final SSLConnectionSocketFactory socketFactory = new SSLConnectionSocketFactory(sslContext, INSTANCE);

            final HttpClient httpClient = custom()
                    .setSSLSocketFactory(socketFactory)
                    .setMaxConnTotal(1000)
                    .setMaxConnPerRoute(40)
                    .build();

            final HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory requestFactory = new HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory(httpClient);

            restTemplate.setRequestFactory(new BufferingClientHttpRequestFactory(requestFactory));
```

And the call:

```
HttpEntity<String> entity = new HttpEntity<>(httpHeaders);
final ResponseEntity<MyList> response = restTemplate.exchange("https://REMOTE_URI/sameObjects", GET, entity, MyList.class);
```

I tried header with differents values (User-Agent, Host, ..) and `ResponseEntity<Object>` , but I have always the same error :

```
org.springframework.web.client.HttpClientErrorException$Forbidden: 403 Forbidden: [no body]
```

I can access it with Postman with the p12 certificate.

Thank you for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution, I change RestTemplate :

```
  public RestTemplate getRestTemplate() {

        try {
            final KeyStore keyStore = KeyStore.getInstance(keyStoreType);
            keyStore.load(keyStoreFile.getInputStream(), keyPassword.toCharArray());


            final SSLContext sslContext = new SSLContextBuilder()
                    .loadTrustMaterial(keyStoreFile.getURL(), keyPassword.toCharArray(), (X509Certificate[] chain, String authType) -> true)
                    .loadKeyMaterial(keyStore, keyPassword.toCharArray())
                    .build();
            final SSLConnectionSocketFactory socketFactory = new SSLConnectionSocketFactory(sslContext, INSTANCE);

            final HttpClient httpClient = custom()
                    .setSSLSocketFactory(socketFactory)
                    .build();

            final HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory requestFactory = new HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory(httpClient);

            final RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
            restTemplate.setRequestFactory(new BufferingClientHttpRequestFactory(requestFactory));

            return restTemplate;
        } catch (IOException e) {
            log.error("....", e);
            throw new ApiException(e);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            log.error("....", e);
            throw new ApiException(e);
        }
    }
```

Comment: So finally the only thing you've added is just `keyStore` initialized and added to `SSLContext`?

Comment: Yes exactly.

But it must be this way